# Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoFill is not defined

Tags: javascript, web-services, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-webpages, scriptservice

I have created web service and trying to call it from java script by enabling its "ScriptService" attribute. But i am getting console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoFill is not defined" I have registered its reference in script manager but no luck.

**AutoFill.asmx**

```
namespace eService
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for AutoFill
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AutoFill : WebService
{

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string DismissAlertNotification(int ID, int CompanyID, string SectionName)
    {


}
```

**header.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="header.ascx.cs" Inherits="ePrint.Templates.header" %>


<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="smproxy" runat="server">
<Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/EprintService/AutoFill.asmx" />
</Services>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function dismiss_alert_notification(ID, CompantID, SectionName) {

    AutoFill.DismissAlertNotification(ID, CompantID, SectionName, onResponse);
}
</script>
```